# Finding minimum value of a table

Tags: c#

I need to find the value and position of the lowest entry in the table. Problem is, I don't know how to specify it. I can't put any numeric in the int value for minimum because the user can always specify a higher value. It works for the highest value but it doesn't for the smallest.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Podaj wymiar tablicy.");
        int dlugosc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] tablica = new int[dlugosc];
        int max = 0;
        int min = tablica[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Podaj wartosc {0} elementu.", i + 1);
            tablica[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.Length; i++)
        {
            while (tablica[i] > max)
            {
                max = tablica[i];
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < tablica.Length; x++)
        {
            while (tablica[x] < min)
            {
                min = tablica[x];
            }
        }
        int najmniejsze_miejsce = Array.IndexOf(tablica, min);
        int najwieksze_miejsce = Array.IndexOf(tablica, max);
        Console.WriteLine("Najwyzsza wartosc tablicy to {0}.", max);
        Console.WriteLine("Najwieksza wartosc wystepuje na miejscu {0}.", najwieksze_miejsce);
        Console.WriteLine("Najniższa wartość tablicy to {0}.", min);
        Console.WriteLine("Najnizsza wartosc wystepuje na miejscu {0}", najmniejsze_miejsce);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code is below:

```
int min = tablica[0];
for (int i = 0; i < tablica.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Podaj wartosc {0} elementu.", i + 1);
    tablica[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

The min value being declared before the array is initialized means it will simply be zero. No value from your array can ever be less unless it's a negative number.

To fix, the min should be declared after the array is initialized:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tablica.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Podaj wartosc {0} elementu.", i + 1);
    tablica[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
int min = tablica[0];`
```

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted you, but you answer is the most correct. But the code should use `int max = tablica[0];` too because the original code will fail if all the numbers are negatives. Funny thing is, the original code will correctly find the min value if all numbers are negatives.

Answer (score 4):

you can just use:

```
Console.WriteLine(tablica.Min());
```

since your using an integer array

Comment: Don’t forget to add `using System.Linq;` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first occurence of the min value in your table

```
int minIndex = Array.IndexOf(tablica, tablica.Min());
```

or simple:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Array.IndexOf(tablica, tablica.Min())));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do need to do a scan you typically set the min value to `Int.MaxValue` and the max value to `Int.MinValue` before the loop and then you are guaranteed to set it on the first element and any element that improves either value.

You can then do it all in one loop (and you don't need to use `while` when you mean `if`). You can also track the index as you go:

```
int max = Int.MinValue;
int min = Int.MaxValue;
int maxindex = -1;
int minindex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < tablica.Length; i++)
{
   if (tablica[i] > max) { max = tablica[i]; maxindex = i; }
   if (tablica[i] < min) { min = tablica[i]; minindex = i; }
}
```